# Javascript centered static text jumps around

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a notification bar that alternates between text, but also has static text beside it. I'd like to centre the text, however when the animated text rotates through, it obviously displaces the static text to recenter the entire string.

Here is the Javascript i'm using

```
var cnt=0, texts=[];

// save the texts in an array for re-use
$(".textContent").each(function() {
  texts[cnt++]=$(this).text();
});
function slide() {
  if (cnt>=texts.length) cnt=0;
  $('#textMessage').html(texts[cnt++]);
  $('#textMessage')
    .fadeIn('slow').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 5000).fadeOut('slow', 
     function() {
       return slide()
     }
  );      
}      
slide()
```

Here is a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/km8pq66j/4/) with the html and css

What I'm hoping to acheive is to get the static text to animate and slide over, rather than just jumping over. Anybody have any insights on this?

Comment: you can do animate twice, one for static text and other for following text

Comment: Might be possible with `position relative` and `getComputedStyle`, will try to post something when I get to my desk. Meanwhile you can try with it.